# Как вытащить отзывы о приложении с сайта PlayMarket с помощью Jsoup?

Tags: java, html5, jsoup, xmlparser, parse

Хочу вытащить комментарии с сайта PlayMarket о приложении с помощью parsing используя Jsoup. Трудности возникли из-за атрибута jsname в тегах span:

```html
<div jscontroller="LVJlx" class="UD7Dzf">
  <span jsname="bN97Pc">Чей-то комментарий</span>
</div>
```

Как получить комментарий, если при parsing теги с атрибутами jsname не выводится на консоль?

Comment: Сначала посмотрите, что приходит из сайта. Там тех данных в html может и не быть, т.к. они могут рендериться из javascript

Comment: Отзывы о приложении на play.google.com отображаются при помощи Javascript. Поэтому Jsoup для этой цели вам не подойдет, так как Jsoup — это лишь HTML-парсер. Для того, чтобы выполнить Javascript, вам нужен полноценный движок Javascript. Посмотрите в сторону Selenium или его аналоги.